# Error: can't convert Array to String when calling custom function that returns an array

Tags: ruby, puppet

Goal: Declare a Puppet file resource that will create all its parent directories if they are missing.

This ruby code works outside puppet:

```
def get_parent_directories(path)
  ancestors = []
  while (match = %r{(^.+[^:/])/}.match(path))
    ancestors.unshift (path = match[1])
  end
  ancestors
end

testpath = "c:/this/is/a/long/path/to/my/file.txt"
paths = get_parent_directories(testpath)
puts paths.join(", ")
```

It  gives the following result:

```
c:/this, c:/this/is, c:/this/is/a, c:/this/is/a/long, c:/this/is/a/long/path, c:/this/is/a/long/path/to, c:/this/is/a/long/path/to/my
```

I then create a Puppet custom function:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:get_parent_directories, :type => :rvalue) do |path|
    ancestors = []
    while (match = %r{(^.+[^:/])/}.match(path))
      ancestors.unshift (path = match[1])
    end
    ancestors
  end
end
```

I put the function under my module's directory:

```
C:\phx_deployer\puppet\modules\dotnet\lib\puppet\parser\functions\get_parent_directories.rb
```

In the init.pp file for my dotnet defined resource type, I attempt to call the function to get an array of directories to be created if they are missing:

```
...
  $temp_file = "${temp_dir}/Install ${version}.exe"
  notify{"temp_file is: ${temp_file}": }
  #$temp_directories = get_parent_directories($temp_file)
  $temp_directories = ['c:/phx_deployer', 'c:/phx_deployer/staging', 'c:/phx_deployer/staging/dotnet']
  notify{"Temp directories are: ${temp_directories}": }
  file { $temp_directories:
    ensure => "directory",
    mode   => '750',
  }
...
```

As shown above, I have commented out the function call and it works, creating the necessary directories because I hard-coded the array $temp_directories. If I try to call the function instead, I get the error:

```
Error: can't convert Array to String at c:/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/dotnet/manifests/init.pp:22 on node usb-tg2008r2t1.ef.com
Wrapped exception:
can't convert Array to String
Error: can't convert Array to String at c:/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/dotnet/manifests/init.pp:22 on node usb-tg2008r2t1.ef.com
```

What am I doing wrong? Do you have to do something special to have a function return an array? I have seen other posts on the internet of people trying to create multiple directories at once in Puppet just like I am, but none posted the final working answer.

NOTE: I successfully ran this to make sure there were no syntax errors:

```
ruby -rpuppet get_parent_directories.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The argument list passed in to the custom function is given as an array, not a scalar.

I rewrote my function this way and it works:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:get_parent_directories, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    path = args[0]
    ancestors = []
    while (match = %r{(^.+[^:/])/}.match(path))
      ancestors.unshift (path = match[1])
    end
    ancestors
  end
end
```

Notice that I have to unpack "path" from "args".